# How to search for multiple Values within Sheets and copy them?

Tags: excel, vba

This code loops through all sheets, looking for specific values ("08" and "09") within the sheets.
If found then paste entire row in a new sheet.

I'm struggling with adding more values to search. So not only values "08", "09" but also for example "10", "11" and so on.

```vb
Sub Filter()
Dim ws As Worksheet, i%, C As Range, D As Range, E As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(before:=Worksheets(1))
For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
    With Worksheets(i)
        Set C = .Columns("A").Find(What:="Day", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Set D = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(1, 4)
        Set E = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2)
        E = C.Value: E(2) = "'08": E(3) = "'09"
        .Range(C, D).AdvancedFilter 2, E.Resize(3), E(4), False
        E.Resize(3 - CInt(E.Row <> 2)).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: A comment, not a solution to your issue... using variables with meaning helps provide longevity to your code, so when you look back later, you have a better handle on what *may* need to be changed.  E.g., `dim b as variant` versus `dim dynamicArray as variant`.

Comment: Add `E(4) = "'10"` etc and then update the 3's following that to [number of values filtered]+1

Comment: I tried a different approach, I think I need to make it as simple as possible to get better grasp of it. With it can now search for different values, however it only sets the value which matches in the other sheets (keyword=row.value then set same value). I tried to get it to copy the whole row if the value matches but I did not get it to work. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array for the values to be filtered, and you only need to create the criteria range once.

Try this:

```vb
Sub Filter()
    
    Const DAY_HDR As String = "Day"  'use Const for fixed values
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i%, C As Range, D As Range
    Dim arrFilt, sz As Long, rngFilt As Range, wb As Workbook
    
    arrFilt = Array("08", "09", "10", "11")      'all filter values
    sz = 1 + (UBound(arrFilt) - LBound(arrFilt)) '# of filter values
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook  'or ThisWorkbook, but best to be explicit
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1))
    ws.Name = "Filtered values"
    ws.Range("A2").Value = DAY_HDR 'adding the criteria range once on the new sheet...
    With ws.Range("A3").Resize(sz)
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = Application.Transpose(arrFilt)
    End With
    Set rngFilt = ws.Range("A2").Resize(sz + 1) 'set the filter range
    
    For i = 2 To wb.Worksheets.Count
      With Worksheets(i)
        Set C = .Columns("A").Find(What:=DAY_HDR, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        Set D = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3)
        
        .Range(C, D).AdvancedFilter 2, rngFilt, _
            ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2), False
      
      End With
    Next
    
    rngFilt.EntireRow.Delete 'remove the criteria range
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub count()
totalsheets = Worksheets.count

mykeyword = Worksheets("Mastersheet").Cells(2, 19).Value
mykeyword2 = Worksheets("Mastersheet").Cells(3, 19).Value
Dim message As String

For i = 1 To totalsheets

If Worksheets(i).Name <> "Mastersheet" Then
    lastrow = Worksheets(i).Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 8 To lastrow
    
    If Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 1).Value = mykeyword Then
    
    Worksheets("Mastersheet").Activate
    
    lastrow = Worksheets("Mastersheet").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Mastersheet").Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 1).Value

ElseIf Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 1).Value = mykeyword2 Then
    Worksheets("Mastersheet").Activate
    
    lastrow = Worksheets("Mastersheet").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Mastersheet").Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 1).Value

    End If


 Next
 
 End If
 Next


End Sub
```